# Переход от VB к C#

Tags: c#, visual-basic

Я уже создавал тему, о том стоит ли переходить от одного в другому. Но вот сейчас проблема. Я начал учить C#, но постоянно путаюсь с переменными, операторами и т.д из VB.NET. Скажите, как можно переучиться на C#? Читаю книги и многое не понимаю, или представляю их как-бы они работали в VB.NET, и потом путаюсь. Как быть в этой ситуации?

Answer (score 1):

По совету Ильича: учиться, учиться и еще раз учиться.

Comment: Да но надо как-то забыть VB...(( Но как не знаю.

Comment: как еще? работать, тренироваться, писать небольшие програмки. Побольше практики. И упорства. Со временем все будет в порядке. То, что Вы описываете, вполне нормально. Не отчаиваться и упорно идти вперед.